# Change private key for DigitalOcean SSH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, digital-ocean, putty

I have private key that I use to ssh login to my digitalocean server,
the private has a pass phrase,

I need to enter every time I login, I want to change that with a new private key that has no pass phrase.

I also have it asks for pass when I pull from my private github.

I can't automate my actions because of that.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is only because of passphrase you need to change your SSH key, you can remove the passphrase by following the steps below:

```
ssh-keygen -p

Enter old passphrase

Enter new passphrase - [Leave it blank]

Confirm new passphrase - [Leave it blank]
```

If you really need a second SSH key, just create one and put your SSH public key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file in your DigitalOcean droplet. You should then be able to login using your new private key.